# Refresh screen or component when navigate to it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two screens, one for displaying the records consuming an API and the other for registering.

the problem is that when I do a register and navigate to the **display screen it does not update.**

This is a construction of the screen:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isLoading: true, pendIsLoading: true, dataSource: [], contentStorageS:""}
  };

  fetchDados = async () => {
    let usuario = await AsyncStorage.getItem("ASCOFAR_app_usuario");

    try {
      const response = await api.get("api/listaRegistros.php?usuario="+usuario);
      const responseData = await response.data
      if(responseData.status == "ERRO"){
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: "",
        })
      }else{
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseData,
        })
      }
      console.log(response)

    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error)
    }
  }

async componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchDados();
    this.atualizaState();
  }

    tirarLoad() {
      if(this.state.isLoading == true){
        return (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#be152c"/>
        )
      }else if(this.state.dataSource == ""){
        return (
          <ScrollView >
            <View style={{justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center",}}>
              <Image
                style ={{width:150, height:150, marginTop:35}}
                source={require('../assets/images/aguardando.png')}
              />
            </View>

          </ScrollView>
        )
      }else{
        return (
          <ScrollView>
            <Text style={styles.tituloGrid}>Formularios Enviados</Text>
            {this.state.dataSource.map(dados => (
              <View style={styles.list} key={dados.id}>
                <Text style={styles.listChild}>{dados.id}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.listChild}>{dados.nome}</Text>
                <Text>|</Text>
                <Text style={styles.listChild}>{dados.endereco}</Text>
              </View>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        )
      }
    }

<View style={styles.grid}>
   {this.tirarLoad()}
</View>
```

I need to know how to do when navigating to this screen to update API consumption

Comment: how do you navigate to `display screen` after  registering

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";

this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      () => {

        this.refreshFetch();
        this.refreshLocal();

      }
    );

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using React-Navigation, did you try to addListener

`focus` [react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html#__docusaurus)

You could also do it by `componentDidUpdate`. I could not find the official documentation for doing it on 5.x. I believe it still works with 5.x. ([Doc on 3.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/function-after-focusing-screen.html))

```js
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
      this.fetchDados()
      //or other similar onFocus function
    }
  }

export default withNavigationFocus(TabScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-rendering your Home screen after navigation

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
      onBack: () => this.refresh() //function to refresh screen,
    });
```

Comment: did your screen refreshed after navigation?